# Confusion matrix plot in r

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have a computed confusion matrix from google earth engine that I would like to use in r to derive a plot. how do I manually enter the confusion matrix and plot in R?. This is the confusion matrix:

1:[141,17,3,6,0,0,39,2]
2:[9,287,0,6,17,0,51,0]
3:[31,1,8,14,9,0,29,1]
4:[2,2,0,179,24,0,23,30]
5:[1,10,0,17,78,0,69,1]
6:[0,0,0,15,3,0,3,16]
7:[22,41,3,12,45,0,380,0]
8:[12,0,3,60,1,0,4,204]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `image` function, you can:

```
# import your data values
z = c(141,17,3,6,0,0,39,2,
      9,287,0,6,17,0,51,0,
      31,1,8,14,9,0,29,1,
      2,2,0,179,24,0,23,30,
      1,10,0,17,78,0,69,1,
      0,0,0,15,3,0,3,16,
      22,41,3,12,45,0,380,0,
      12,0,3,60,1,0,4,204)

# create a matrix
z = matrix(z, ncol = 8)

# set rows and columns names
colnames(z) = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")
rownames(z) = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")

##To get the correct image plot rotation
##We need to flip the plot
image(z[,ncol(z):1], axes = FALSE)

##Add in the y-axis labels. Similar idea for x-axis.
axis(2, at = seq(0, 1, length=length(colnames(z))), labels = colnames(z))
```

And here is your output
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you so much!, I've used the code and replaced the column and row numbers with names as well, but is there a way to get a scale to relate the values to the colors?

Comment: You mean like a legend?

Comment: yes if possible

Comment: There are options with `ggplot2` (e.g.,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897252/plot-confusion-matrix-in-r-using-ggplot). But this a question for an other topic I think

Comment: Also, when someone's answer solved your problem please read this https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: Thank you, have ticked the answer